# When is bootstrapping needed in helib?

Tags: c++, cryptography

I was under the impression that somewhat homomorphic encryption schemes allow you to perform an arbitrary number of additions followed by a single multiplication, after which noise gets too large. But when I try the following it seems to work:

```
publicKey.Encrypt(ctx1, to_ZZX(2));
publicKey.Encrypt(ctx2, to_ZZX(3));
publicKey.Encrypt(ctx3, to_ZZX(10));

Ctxt ctRes = ctx1;
ctRes += ctx2;
ctRes *= ctx3;
ctRes *= ctx3;

ZZX ptRes;
secretKey.Decrypt(ptRes, ctRes);
std::cout << "(2 + 3) * 10 * 10= " << ptRes[0] << std::endl;
```

Performing one more multiplication produces the wrong result.

Is the number and/or kind of operations allowed before bootstrapping is needed predictable? What does it depend on? The underlying values or any of the initialization parameters?

Comment: I don't have time to answer now, but there is an implicit parameter named L, which stands to "level" and says how many multiplication you may perform in sequence (so, in your example, it seems that L = 2). Take a look at the examples in the code of the own Helib...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The amount of computation that can be performed by your specific instance is heavily dependent on the parameters used to initialize the system. In general, multiplication (or operations that involve multiplication) are the most costly.

The "L" parameter, indicative of the number of levels in the modulus chain, is the most significant factor in how many computations (and multiplications, specifically) can be performed before bootstrapping is needed. Try setting that to a larger number.

I strongly recommend reading through Test_General.cpp in HElib's src folder, which can be downloaded here: https://github.com/shaih/HElib. You can run "make" in that folder to generate an executable called Test_General_x and run it with "Test_General_x L=10 R=5" to set L to 10 and run 5 rounds of those computations (which you could change in the source code). Play around with the various parameters, changing L to 15,20,...,60, or change other parameters and see how it affects the runtime, number of computations you can perform, and decryption errors.

If you need to bootstrap, you can look into params.cpp in that same src file and test various parameters for bootstrapping by running "params_x ..." according to the instructions at the bottom of params.cpp